# Regex -> only letters and end with a dot

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to select all the tokens that contain only letters or only letters and end with a dot.

Example of valid words : `"abc", "abc."`
Invalid `"a.b" "a2"`

i've tried this

```
string[] tokens = text.Split(' ');
var words = from token in tokens 
            where Regex.IsMatch(token,"^[a-zA-Z]+.?$")
            select token;
```

`^[a-zA-Z]+`  - only letters one or more times and start with letter

`.?$` = ends with 0 or 1 dot ?? not sure about this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In regex, an unescaped `.` pattern matches *any* character (including digits). Thus, your regex would undesirably match tokens such as `"a2"`.

You need to escape your dot character as `\.`.

```
string[] tokens = text.Split(' ');
var words = from token in tokens 
            where Regex.IsMatch(token,@"^[a-zA-Z]+\.?$")
            select token;
```

**Edit**: Furthermore, you can amalgamate your `Split(' ')` logic into your regex by using lookbehind and lookahead. This might improve efficiency, although it does reduce legibility a bit.

```
var words = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=\ |^)[a-zA-Z]+\.?(?=\ |$)")
                 .OfType<Match>()
                 .Select(m => m.Value);
```

- The `(?<=\ |^)` lookbehind means that the match must be preceded by a space or start-of-string.
- The `(?=\ |$)` lookahead means that the match must be succeeded by a space or end-of-string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `.`

```
^[a-zA-Z]+\.?$
```

Otherwise, `.` is a special character that matches (almost) all characters--not just periods.